# How to return specific attributes for all users in LDAP Java?

Tags: java, search, attributes, ldap, jndi

I am trying to return employee numbers of everyone in search filter

```
(&(employeeType= Workforce)(objectClass=person))
```

This is my code:

```
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingEnumeration;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attributes;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchControls;
import javax.naming.directory.SearchResult;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.ldap.InitialLdapContext;
import javax.naming.ldap.LdapContext;

public class testing2 {
    public testing2() {

    }

    public void doLookup() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
        properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "removed for reasons");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"simple");
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,"removed"); 
        properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,"secret");
        try {
            DirContext context = new InitialDirContext(properties);
            SearchControls searchCtrls = new SearchControls();
            searchCtrls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
            String filter = "(&(employeeType= Workforce)(objectClass=person))";
            NamingEnumeration values = context.search("o = xyz",filter,searchCtrls);
            while (values.hasMoreElements())
            {
                SearchResult result = (SearchResult) values.next();
                Attributes attribs = result.getAttributes();

                if (null != attribs)
                {
                    for (NamingEnumeration ae = attribs.getAll(); ae.hasMoreElements();)
                    {
                        Attribute atr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                        String attributeID = atr.getID();
                        for (Enumeration vals = atr.getAll(); 
                            vals.hasMoreElements(); 
                            System.out.println(attributeID +": "+ vals.nextElement()));
                            //System.out.println(attributeID.getAttributes().get("uid"))
                    }
                }
            }

            context.close();

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        testing2 sample = new testing2();
        sample.doLookup();
    }

}
```

The thing is that when I run this, I get everything/all information about all the users - including attributes like first name, last name, title, givenName, postal code, employee number and more. How do I go about JUST extracting/returning the employee numbers only (for all users within the filter)

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, you search returns full LDAP items, but you can get directly needed attribute without read them all: did you try to use

    Attribute myattrib = attribs.get("employeeNumber") 

instead to loop on whole Attributes? Or maybe I misunderstood your question?

Comment: @Sampisa  
Hello. When I do that, it returns "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to javax.naming.directory.Attribute" ... Thank you (you did not misunderstand my question)

Comment: Hmmm this is quite strange. A Attributes object has method get used to exactly get (!) a single Attribute, that is internally stored in a Hashtable of a BasicAttributes. Can you check - in case "get" returns a String and not a Attribute (!) - what is the value reported by that String? This really sounds strange to me

Comment: I think I messed up completely with `Attribute myattrib = attribs.get("employeeNumber")`  to loop... I just removed it as I don't know where to put loop since the previous one returned the strange error.  Can you check original post I added an edit. I'm completely new to Java and this has caused me some confusion. Appreciate the help very much. @Sampisa

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the class cast exception in your question. The code supplied by @Sampisa is correct.

Comment: @Sampisa Indeed. If it really returns a String why did it even compile?

Comment: Hello. Managed to get a fix! Look in the original post edits.

Comment: So what was this impossible class cast exception business all about? In addition to @Sampisa's suggestion you should also do `searchControls.setReturningAttributes(new String[]{"employeeNumber"});`, for efficiency reasons.

Comment: @FelixSFD What on earth do you think you're doing?

Comment: @EJP Answers should be posted as **answers** and not be added to the question. I think you should know this as an experienced user. If the asker solved his problem, he can add a self-anwer instead.

Comment: Solutions should be posted as answers not as updates to the question. This is to avoid confusion for future visitors. Thank you.

Comment: @FelixSFD The OP has specifically denied in comments that the solution he now gives works. There is an ongoing discussion about this which is rendered meaningless by your edit.

Answer (score 0):

@Sampisa's solution was correct:

```
if (null != attribs) {
    Attribute myattrib = attribs.get("employeeNumber");
    System.out.println(myattrib); // or myattrib.get(0)
 }
```

instead of

```
 if (null != attribs)
            {
                for (NamingEnumeration ae = attribs.getAll(); ae.hasMoreElements();)
                {
                    Attribute atr = (Attribute) ae.next();
                    String attributeID = atr.getID();
                    for (Enumeration vals = atr.getAll(); 
                        vals.hasMoreElements(); 
                        System.out.println(attributeID +": "+ vals.nextElement()));
                        //System.out.println(attributeID.getAttributes().get("uid"))
                }
            }
```

Comment: Alternative to what? And how come this doesn't throw a `ClassCastException` as you claimed in comments? Please explain.

Comment: This is a different solution that never threw a ClassCastException though

Comment: No it isn't. This is exactly what @Sampisa suggested.

Comment: I suppose that @IAmAboutToFailLol mis-typed something after my suggestion, or he didn't understand it correctly. I suppose question is closed.

Comment: @Sampisa No doubt about it, but he should nevertheless give credit where credit is due, and not pretend that he came up with an alternative to your suggestion when he didn't.

Comment: @EJP Probably his global procedure wasn't correct, maybe he wasn't too precise in his request, but I think that he received both help and answer, and this is a success, from my PoV, and at the same time offered a general overview of what can happen in cases like this (helping also other users reading here). So, if answers helped him to understand his problem, it's ok for me... no matter if he didn't give "credits" to people who answered, or if he thinks to have found his own answer even if it isn't. He found a solution, and this is enough, for me :) Indeed, thank you for your comment.